# How do I assign usernames to a ROBLOX Team Spawner?

Tags: roblox

I would like to know how to assign certain usernames to a team spawner.

Basically when a certain username joins the game, they get placed into a team on the leader board and spawn at the correct spawn in game.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by checking the username and assigning the team. So something like this, assuming you don't have teams already set up.

```
team = Instance.new("Team",game:GetService'Teams')
game:GetService'Players'.PlayerAdded:connect(function(p)
     if p.Name == "name" then
          p.Team = team
     end
end
```

Obviously you can set the team name and color through this script or create it your own.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do the player handling yourself. Basically you want to listen on new players with [PlayerAdded](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/Players/PlayerAdded) and set the team (based on some kind of magical function) with [Team](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/Player/Team).

However you can assign [Spawners](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/SpawnLocation) to a [team](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/Team) by setting the [TeamColor](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/SpawnLocation/TeamColor) to equal the Team's [TeamColor](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/Team/TeamColor).

---

Example code:

```
local Teams = game:GetService("Teams")
local RedTeam = Teams["Red Team"]
local OtherTeam = Teams["Other Team"]
local PlayersInTeamRed = { "Player1" , "Player2" }

game:GetService("Players").PlayerAdded:connect(function(player)
    for playerName in ipairs(PlayersInTeamRed) do
        if player.Name == playerName then
            player.Team = RedTeam
            return
        end
    end

    -- Maybe another list here

    -- not in "Team red"
    player.Team = OtherTeam
end)
```

Note that you might want to check against the [UserId](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/Player/UserId) instead, because some players changes their name.

Also make sure that the Spawn's [Neutral value](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/SpawnLocation/Neutral) is false.